# Pick (5) numbers and (1) modified numbers from a list and print the sum from those numbers that meets a specified range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to do the following using Excel VBA:

- [1]   30 numbers (Input manually in Excel)
- [2]   Pick 1 number from [1] and x 1.5
- [3]   Pick another 5 numbers from [1]
- [4]   Sum all values from [2] and [3]
- [5]   Define a min and max range for the sum
- [6]   Print out all the sum from [4] that meet range [5]

I was creating an array of the 30 numbers, create a loop of each element, eliminate that element in the array so it would not double count and sum it up. However, I'm not sure what is the logic of this should be to incorporate the value from [2].

Comment: What code have you tried?  Please edit your question and post.

Comment: Additional point, have you looked into [`Rnd()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a slightly different process:

1. Create your array of 30 numbers
2. Randomly select *6* numbers from that array
3. multiply the first of the 6 numbers by 1.5
4. etc. as you have specified.

EDIT: Example code below:

```vb
Sub PickSixNumbers()
'Set variables:
Dim lBigArray(1 To 30) As Variant, lSmallArray(1 To 6) As Long

'Putting some fake values in here, over to you to fix this bit:
For a = 1 To 30
    lBigArray(a) = a
Next

'Pick your numbers:
a = 1
Do Until a > 6
    lSmallArray(a) = lBigArray(RndIntegerBetween(1, 30))
    'If the selected number has already been selected, don't move to the next one
    If CountInArray(lSmallArray, lSmallArray(a)) = 1 Then a = a + 1
Loop

'Multiply the first one by 1.5
lSmallArray(1) = lSmallArray(1) * 1.5

If WorksheetFunction.Sum(lSmallArray) > 0 And WorksheetFunction.Sum(lSmallArray) < 100 Then
    Debug.Print "Sum is between 0 and 100"
Else
    Debug.Print "Sum is not between 0 and 100"
    Debug.Print "SHOCK HORROR"
End If

End Sub

'Helper Functions:
Function CountInArray(arr() As Long, Value As Long) As Long
CountInArray = 0
For a = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If arr(a) = Value Then CountInArray = CountInArray + 1
Next
End Function

Function RndIntegerBetween(Min As Long, Max As Long) As Long
RndIntegerBetween = Int((Max - Min + 1) * Rnd + Min)
End Function
```